# styling tooltips in AmCharts (V4)

Tags: amcharts

currently im trying to style a tooltip which appears when you hover over an map image with dynamic content (title of the company).

My aim is to style the background to a specific color, give the font a color and also apply a CSS property "box-shadow".

For the first aim I tried to use the "fill" property like so:

mapImageSeries is of type am4maps.MapImageSeries.

```
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.fill = am4core.color('#ffff00');
```

Which does not work however using

```
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 0;  // will change the "border-radius" of the tooltip. 

this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color('#ffff00'); // does also not work.
```

For my second goal setting up a color property for the font I didn't find a property, same with the box-shadow css property.

Is it possible to attach a css class for the tooltip so I can easily style it via CSS? And how do I style the tooltip with the 
requirements im facing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, tooltips pull colors from their relevant object, so to manipulate their styles you'll first have to [turn that off](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/overriding-series-tooltip-fill-color/), e.g.:

```js
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
```

You can then do:

```js
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 0;
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#ffff00");
```

Instead of modifying CSS `box-shadow`, you can apply [the `DropShadow` SVG filter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-filters/#Available_filters). `Tooltip`s have a single filter, actually a `DropShadow` filter out the box, which we can modify:

```js
var dropShadow = this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.filters.getIndex(0);
dropShadow.dx = 3;
dropShadow.dy = 3;
dropShadow.blur = 5;
dropShadow.opacity = 0.7;
```

To modify `Tooltip` text styles, they actually have their own `Label` child via their `label` property. There are two ways you can modify color, first is like the method above, e.g. if you want to set a default color for tooltip text:

```js
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color("#e97f02"); // color from lolcolors: https://www.webdesignrankings.com/resources/lolcolors/#palette_18
```

Another way to color the text, as well as apply other CSS styles, is to use [Visual formatting](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Visual_formatting) in your `tooltipText` string, e.g.:

```js
this.mapImageSeries.tooltipText = "[font-size: 20px; #bd1550]{companyTitle}:[/]\n{locationTitle} branch";
```

One style that won't work via visual formatting is `text-align`, you'll need to do that through via SVG properties, e.g.

```js
this.mapImageSeries.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";
```

I've made a demo for you here:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f6d4167ea7ccd5dd47054d2430443c0a/

Hope this helps, let me know if it's all making sense.

If you're still looking to use literally CSS for your own needs, let me know and I'll try to sort that out with you.

Comment: How do I align a specific piece of text to middle in the tooltip?

Comment: Font-size are not getting applied.